# Cocoa: Autosave window not working

Tags: c#, cocoa, window, autosave

I'm trying to save and restore the window bounds using Cocoa with C#. I tried the following according to docs, but it does not work. What I'm missing?

```
   public class MyWindow: NSWindow
   {
    internal MyWindow() : base()
    {

        SetSavedFrame();


        //Attach window will close event to MyWindow_WillClose
        [...]
    }

    [...]

    void SetSavedFrame()
    {
        FrameAutosaveName = AUTOSAVE_NAME;

        if (SetFrameUsingName(FrameAutosaveName, true))
            return;

        SetFrame(new RectangleF (0, 0, DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT), true);
        Center();
    }

    void MyWindow_WillClose(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        SaveFrameUsingName(FrameAutosaveName);
    }
}
```

If I cat the content of my .plist file, it is always the same, so I think the problem is, at least, when saving the preferences.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the frame with AUTOSAVE_NAME in the preferences file what is should be? Is `MyWindow_WillClose` called? Did you try using only automatic (frameAutosaveName) or only manual (setFrameUsingName/saveFrameUsingName) frame saving and restoring?

Comment: Yes, the handler method is called and the .plist file is written, but I find out that it is only written when window is resized (not moved), and not all the times it is resized :S